# Selenium IDE -- capture current date

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I would like to know with selenium is there a way to capture current date,month,year as the applicaion which i use has a seperate date, month, year fields which we need to manually type in. I problem I have here is the test case will only accepts the date <=31 days in future and won't accepts any date in the past. so if I can have a way where I can capture the current date, month, year (Numerical values) which would be useful

for example

```
  <tr>
        <td>type</td>
        <td>form1:txtCoverDateDay</td>
        <td>02</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>type</td>
    <td>form1:txtCoverDateMonth</td>
    <td>11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>form1:txtCoverDateYear</td>
    <td>2011</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: did you find a different solution?

Answer (score 9):

use storeEval

The example below is a fully working selenium test that matches your requirements exactly, to run it open the IDE, click on the Source tab in the main window and paste the code between the `<tbody>` tag

```
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/date-selection.php</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>new Date().setDate( new Date().getDate() + 31);</td>
    <td>date</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${date}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>d=new Date( new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate() + 31); d=d.getFullYear()</td>
    <td>year</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>name=year</td>
    <td>${year}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${year}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>d=new Date( new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate() + 31); d=d.getMonth() + 1</td>
    <td>month</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>name=month</td>
    <td>value=${month}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${month}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>d=new Date( new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate() + 31).getDate(); d= d.toString().length == 1 ? &quot;0&quot; + d : d;</td>
    <td>day</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>name=dt</td>
    <td>label=${day}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${day}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

I've added in the javascript to return a date 31 days in the future.

You can also use a combination of runScript and storeEval to get virtually anything from the page.
A question I've asked demonstrates the idea

[Load an external js file containing useful test functions in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675492/load-an-external-js-file-containing-useful-test-functions-in-selenium)

Any other questions add a comment, and I'll be happy to help :)

See @icc97 comment to add zero padding to the dates.

Comment: Thanks for the your answer but it looks like it is storing the date month and year but does it automatically pick the date when i run the test case in future date???

Comment: Yes the example I've given above stores and echoes the date components, but you can use selenium to take the stored value and enter them in to a form.  I'll amend the answer to demo.

Comment: I've edited the answer, the test runs perfectly on the page at http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/date-selection.php

Comment: looks like all three of your date inputs are text inputs, just copy the code for the year and amend the selector to target the correct inputs

Comment: For `YYYY-MM-DD` format: `d=d.getFullYear()+'-'+('0' + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)+'-'+('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2)` the zero padding is from http://stackoverflow.com/a/9744576/327074