# Load an external js file containing useful test functions in selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

The runScript command in selenium is really useful, and I'm using it to total values in a table and then store the value like this

```
<tr>
    <td>runScript</td>
    <td>var cumulative = 0.0; $('table.quote-review-group-component').eq(0).find('tr').each( function( i,el ){var singleStackTotal = $(el).find('td').eq(4).html();if( singleStackTotal ){cumulative += parseFloat( singleStackTotal.substring(1) );} }); cumulative = cumulative.toFixed(2)</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>selenium.browserbot.getUserWindow().cumulative</td>
    <td>cumulative</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${cumulative}</td>

    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyEquals</td>
    <td>£${cumulative}</td>
    <td>${total}</td>
</tr>
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to point to an external js file rather than have the javascript in the command as a string, so that I can load in some test functions and use storeEval to get the return of the function

So we'd have

```
<tr>
    <td>runExternalScript</td>
    <td>/path/to/external/extra-tests.js</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>selenium.browserbot.getUserWindow().getCumulative(0)</td>
    <td>cumulative0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyEquals</td>
    <td>£${cumulative}</td>
    <td>${total}</td>
</tr>
```

And the external script would look like this

```
function checkSingleGroupListTotal( index ){
    if ( index == "undefined" ){
        index = 0;
    }
    var cumulative = 0.0; 
    $('table.quote-review-group-component').eq(index).find('tr').each( function( i,el ){
        var singleStackTotal = $(el).find('td').eq(4).html();    
        if( singleStackTotal ){         
            cumulative += parseFloat( singleStackTotal.substring(1) );     
        } 
    }); 
    return cumulative.toFixed(2);
}
```

Thinking about it a plugin which adds a loadScript action which checks for the external js file and then passes the file contents to runScript would do the job.  But I don't want to reinvent the wheel, and I've never built a plug in before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `runScript` command merely adds a `<SCRIPT>` element containing the script to the DOM and lets the browser run it.  You can do the same yourself, and instead of an in-line script, use the `SRC=` attribute to tell the browser what file to load.  You may have to load the file from a web server, because some browsers won't allow page loaded from the net to access a `file:` URL.

Comment: Do you mean add a script tag to the page I'm testing?

Comment: Nope, I mean doing exactly what Selenium does, but a little different:

var doc = this.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().document;
var scriptTag = doc.createElement("script");
scriptTag.type = "text/javascript"
scriptTag.src = 'your_script_URL_goes_here';
doc.body.appendChild(scriptTag);

Comment: Thanks for this Ross, I've not tested this yet.  Do you mean that I use storeEval to run this javascript in the IDE, or did you have something different in mind?