# how to embed an external javascript file to a c# selenium test unit?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium

I'm using visual studio to write a c# test unit using the selenium webdrive, at some point I've decided to implement a javascript file.

The Javascript file is a little too long to write it directly in the c# code, so I've added an empty Javascript file in Visual studio and copied the code there.

The .js file is visible in the solution explorer but I don't know how to access it from the c# code.

Can you guys provide a sample code on how to access the .js file? thanks.

Comment: Looks similar to another question, try that answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/7693645/1018192

Comment: @maryum375 sorry but I don't think I can use that it. they use the selenium IDE which has a runscript tag and a src=  attribute, but in the selenium webdrive there other commands and attributes.

Comment: Maybe you can load the javascript file to a variable as a string and when you call the `ExecuteScript` method pass that variable...

Comment: @maryum375 if you meant with load the .js file to a string, accessing the file via path, then that's exactly what I was thinking about. yet I can't figure out a way on how to load the content of a file via path. if you you were thinking  about `string script = "script....";` then I would prefer to avoid that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
using System.IO;


IJavaScriptExecutor selenium = _driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
string path = @"Path to your file";
string jsFileContent = File.ReadAllText(path);
selenium.ExecuteScript (jsFileContent);
```

Comment: I think I need a using namespace, right? which one should I use?

Comment: hey thanks a lot and don't bother about my first comment. the code works although it needs some cleanup.